# Get HTML node values with php

Tags: php, html, parsing

I'am parsing an HTML file and getting values of the 'td' tags, what I want is to get are the char values of each string. Here is my code:

```
$content = "";

$data = file_get_contents('https://www.oncf.ma/fr/Horaires? from%5B00229%5D%5B0093%5D=RABAT+AGDAL&to%5B00206%5D%5B0093%5D=CASA+PORT&datedep=27%2F05%2F2018+01%3A00&dateret=&is-ar=0');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($data);
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td');
$i=0;
if(count($items)>0)  
{
    foreach ($items as $heure)
    {    
        $content .= $heure->NodeValue; 
    }   
}
else
{
    $content = $doc->saveHTML();
}
echo $content;
```

I want to get the value of every char of the string: `$heure->NodeValue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its typo here
please replace

```
$heure->NodeValue
```

to

```
$heure->nodeValue
```

Edited

> Please add a line before last echo

```
$content = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $content);
echo $content;
```

Comment: In my code it's $heure->nodeValue and it's working fine i'am getting the values

Comment: Then what's your desired output man? What do you mean by char values of each string?

Comment: I want to get the value of every char in the string: $heure->nodeValue.

Comment: No, for example $heure->nodeValue equals "09h00", i want to get the char 'h' to do a test on it.

Comment: Do you want only string without any digit?

Comment: Yes it may help